# Drawing two parallel lines with a certain distance away

Tags: p5.js

I made a program that creates parallel lines from the mouse coordinates with a certain distance away which can be modified by the distance variable at the beginning of the code. The problem is that it does not work as it should when drawing.

**Line 1 and Line 2 are the lines that are parallel to the line formed from the mouse coordinates, the "pointSlope" variable.**

```
distance = 30
function setup() {
    createCanvas(600, 600);
}

function draw() {
    lineCreate([pmouseX,pmouseY], [mouseX,mouseY])  
}

function lineCreate(point1, point2) {
    fill(0)
    stroke(0)
    x0 = point1[0];
    x1 = point2[0];
    y0 = point1[1];
    y1 = point2[1];
    if (abs(x1 - x0) > abs(y1 - y0)) {
        if (x0 > x1) {
            let t = x0; x0 = x1; x1 = t;
            t = y0; y0 = y1; y1 = t;
        }
        for (let x = x0; x <= x1; x++) {
            let slope = (y1-y0) * (x-x0) / (x1-x0)
            let y = y0 + (y1-y0) * (x-x0) / (x1-x0);
            line1 = y + distance*Math.sqrt(1+pow(slope,2))
            line2 = y - distance*Math.sqrt(1+pow(slope,2))
            circle(x, line1, 2, 2);
            circle(x, line2, 2, 2);
        }
    } else {
        if (y0 > y1) {
            let t = x0; x0 = x1; x1 = t;
            t = y0; y0 = y1; y1 = t;
        }
        for (let y = y0; y <= y1; y++) {
            let x = x0 + (x1-x0) * (y-y0) / (y1-y0);
            circle(x, y, 2, 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Repeating questions to attract attention is not welcome: [Drawing a parallel line with current code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71930632/drawing-a-parallel-line-with-current-code)

Comment: This is a different question and different code. That post does not exist.

Comment: It's a different question and different code

Answer (score 0):

I think that using vectors may help you in this situation, try this code as example:

```
let dist = 40;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
    v = createVector();
    noStroke();
}

function draw() {
  lineCreate();
}

function lineCreate() {
    
    v.x = mouseX-pmouseX;   v.y = mouseY-pmouseY; 
    h = v.heading();
    
    LX = dist*cos(h+PI/2);  LY = dist*sin(h+PI/2);
    RX = dist*cos(h-PI/2);  RY = dist*sin(h-PI/2);
    
    for (let i=0; i<v.mag(); i++) {
        fill(0).circle(pmouseX+i*cos(h),pmouseY+i*sin(h),2);
        fill(160).circle(pmouseX+LX+i*cos(h),pmouseY+LY+i*sin(h),2);
        fill(160).circle(pmouseX+RX+i*cos(h),pmouseY+RY+i*sin(h),2);
    }
    
}
```

Here we are drawing two parallel lines in road-like path, but as you can see there are gaps in turns caused by using `pmouse`. I think, that it will not be possible to get rid of these artifacts, if you not move away from using the `pmouse` to more complex ways of calculating the trajectory.

Comment: How can I adapt this to work with what I have right now? On my current code, I am using mouseX and mouseY and it's working well

Comment: The issue is that you are using not just `mouseX, mouseY`, but they connection with `pmouseX, pmouseY` (previous position of mouse), that's why you have problem with verticals in line 16: `slope = (point2[1]-point1[1])/(point2[0]-point1[0])` — previous and current position of mouseX are the same, so it's division by zero. To adapt the code above and fix this vertical thing you can replace all `sqrt` and `pow` calculations in your code with some [vector math](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Vector).